# How to generate crosstalk between 2 wires?

Tags: inductive, coupling, crosstalk

I'm trying to recreate a situation where crosstalk is occurring. I'm having a bit of trouble trying to inductively cross couple two parallel wires that don't have any shielding or insulation and aren't twisted together. I basically have 2 oscillator circuits that are connected to an inductor since I want to measure the two inductors frequency.

[image]

Comment: maybe try a higher frequency, or a larger loop area.

Comment: A link to a photo of your setup would help :)  Welcome to ESE.

Comment: what is the frequency, voltage and current you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do to increase crosstalk:

- increase frequency
- increase output impedance of circuit that is feeding "secondary" wire
- increase voltage
- increase current through "primary" wire
- increase length of those wires
- decrease distance between those wires

Comment: I've tried all of those. Doesn't seem to have an effect

Comment: @GuyLee add all the details to your question. What exactly did you try. And add schematic.

Comment: Did you put significant current through the 'primary' wire?

Comment: @Whit3rd thanks for comment, I have added that to my answer

Comment: I've added an image of the circuit I'm using. The long wire that connects the inductor is what I'm trying to crosstalk to another passive wire lying in parallel

Comment: The frequency of the oscillator is roughly 40kHz, the voltage is roughly 5V pk-pk. I have no idea how to measure or even increase the current of the circuit

Comment: @GuyLee if you don't know how to measure or increase current, than solving crosstalk is too big task for you. You measure current by ammeter. You increase current by decreasing impedance. Do not ask why/how here, those are completely another questions.

Comment: I'm not trying to solve crosstalk. I'm trying to generate it. I am aware of ammeter's but I don't have one in my university's lab. Only an oscilloscope.

Comment: @Chupacabras I've calculated the output current of the oscillator

Answer (score 3):

Crosstalk is due to either capacitive or inductive coupling.  You seem to assume only inductive coupling, but gave no justification for that.

Capacitive coupling is the easiest to simulate.  Just connect a capacitor between the two wires.  Depending on the length of wire, their spacing, and what insulation is between them, this might take a few pF to a few 100 pF.

For inductive coupling, loop a few turns of each wire around the same ferrite stick.  Make sure to use a ferrite material specified for your frequency.  In this case, the far ends of the wire need to be loaded as they would be in real life.  Inductive coupling is due to current, so you won't get any coupling without current flowing thru the wires.

Comment: Will it be ok to connect a function generator to one end of the wire and then ground the other end of the wire. As for the passive wire, should one end be floating and the other connected to ground?

Comment: Without a diagram *of the system you are trying to emulate*, not your test setup, I'm not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute crosstalk between 2 wires, if you know the frequency and current in wire#1, and know a LOOP (wire+return_path) area of another wire.

Vinduce = [MUo*MUr*Area/(2pi*Distance between Wire#1 and Loop)]*dI/dT

Thus wire carrying 1 amp at 60 Hz has dI/dT of 377 amps/second.

If one meter away from 0.1meter*0.1meter (4" on a side) square loop, with Loop and Wire#1 in the same plane, with no other metallic structures nearby, we have the induced voltage of

[2*1e-7H/meter * 0.1m * 0.1m/1m] * 377 = 2e-9 * 377 = 754 nanoVolts